# Diazo Quickstart - what am I meant to be getting as output?

Tags: python, wsgi, diazo

I'm following the [Diazo Quickstart instructions](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) . I start the proxy and issue a request, I get a response but I'm not sure the response is what I'm meant to be getting.

The Quickstart reads :

> The idea is to run a local webserver that applies the Diazo theme to a
>   response coming from an existing website, either locally or somewhere
>   on the internet

... only that seems inconsistent with this part of the proxy.ini contained in the Quickstart guide ...

```
# Proxy http://diazo.org as the content
[app:content]
use = egg:Paste#proxy
address = http://diazo.org/
suppress_http_headers = accept-encoding
```

... after seeing that I thought what was going to happen was that the content from diazo.org would be embedded within the theme.html and with the theme.css applied to that content .

What actually happens (as far as I can tell) is that if I request ...

```
http://localhost:8000
```

... I receive an unaltered copy of the content at http://diazo.org.

On the other hand if I amend proxy.ini so that the app:content reads as follows ...

```
# Proxy http://diazo.org as the content
[app:content]
use = egg:Paste#proxy
address = http://python.org/
suppress_http_headers = accept-encoding
```

I *don't* get the content of python.org sent to the browser, I get the content of the theme.html file !

The proxy.ini is identical to the once shown in the QuickStart guide except I'm using port 8000 and as mentioned above I've changed the address within the app:content section for the purposes of testing.

So my question is what am I meant to see if I complete the steps in the QuickStart document ? And if it's meant to be a slightly altered version of the diazo.org content (as I suspect) why don't I see the same alterations when I change the target for the proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

modify u rules.xml

```
 <replace css:theme-children="#content" css:content-children=".container" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply and thank you for your comment. I have now tried this and as far as I can tell nothing has changed. When I go to localhost:8000 I still get an unchanged version of docs.diazo.org served to me. It's very frustrating. Anyway I was primarily interested in using this to theme wsgi apps so I'm going to give up on the quick start and when I get a chance try using diazo to theme a wsgi app from scratch.